# Fiat Uno 1100 starting problems

Tags: engine, fiat, cranks-wont-run, uno

I have a Fiat Uno with 1100 engine. The head gasket broke. I have sent the head for skimming. I have changed the oil, plugs, and filters. I put everything back, but it's not starting. There is spark pressure seems good and petrol does come to the carb. It's not even catching little bit it just turns over. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What year is your Uno? Two things to check: 1) Make sure your ignition timing is correct. The spark plugs may be firing, but if they aren't firing correctly, it won't run. 2) Check to ensure your valve timing is correct.

Comment: Thx ill check that can it be that there is a pressure leak.... it seems to turn over very easy when i try to start it. Its a 2002 model. The destubuter can only go in one way so do i need to adjust the cam?

Comment: Just because you have the distributor in the right way doesn't mean you have the wires located correctly. And, no, you don't need to *adjust* the cam, you need to check the timing of it to ensure it's correct. If you determine the cam is incorrectly timed, then you'd need to adjust it.